# How to support both RegEx and Array of exact values for include and exclude in Elasticsearch Java?

Tags: elasticsearch, graphql, graphql-java

I am developing a search API which supports Aggregation using Elasticsearch and GraphQL-Java.

Elasticsearch :- ES supports a feature called as include and exclude, which as the name suggest will include or exclude only those Aggregation fields asked by user in the input.

The include and exclude input can be given in two ways:

1. As RegEx.

   For ex: "include": "P.*"
2. As array of exact values

   For ex:  "include": ["Pune","Mumbai"]

So, to supports both this input, I have maintained a type as

```
input : [String]
```

Problem:  I want to supports both RegEx(String) and Array of exact values[String], but with above type i.e [String], even if I pass a Single String as input in include, it will still be considered as Array of String with one values as

include:"P.*" ---> include:["P.*"],

So I can't do an instanceOf check in Java, as it always will be array

As far as I know GraphQL doesn't support union of input types so I can't change the input type for include as

```
include : String | [String]
```

Can anybody direct me to a solution?

Answer (score 0):

As the problem was due to input type for include and exclude, I defined a custom scalar type in GraphQL name "StringOrArrayOfString"

In GraphQL-Java, this can be done as follow:

```
GraphQLScalarType.newScalar().name("StringOrArrayOfString")
                .description("Custom scalar for include and exclude in Aggregation")
                .coercing(new Coercing() {
                    @Override
                    public Object serialize(Object dataFetcherResult) {
                        return serializeStringOrArrayOfString(dataFetcherResult);
                    }
                    @Override
                    public Object parseValue(Object input) {
                        return parseStringOrArrayOfString(input);
                    }
                    @Override
                    public Object parseLiteral(Object input) { return parseStringOrArrayOfStringLiteral(input); }
                }).build();

private static Object serializeStringOrArrayOfString(Object result) {
        if(result instanceof String) {
            return result.toString();
        }
        if(result instanceof List) {
            return result;
        } else {
            throw new CoercingSerializeException(String.format("Unable to serialize %s.",result));
        }
    }
```

and defined that type for include and exclude.

include : StringOrArrayOfString

Once I get the include/exclude value I check the **instanceOf** and called the appropriate Elasticsearch builder.